# How to highlight selected text in android?

Tags: textview, android

I have created Text View dynamically.I have to set focus/highlight the particular text when i click on that Text View.please suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a listener to control the desired behavior on the "click" event. Something like this:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
});
```

If you want to deselect the selected `TextView` when you click in a new one, just change the background colors of the preciously selected `TextView`.

Android `TextView`'s API [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
text.setFocusable(true);
```

also

```
text.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int blue = 0xff0000ff;
int red = 0xffff0000;
text.setBackgroundColor(blue);
text.setTextColor(red);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findVieById(R.id.my_textview); //replacing my_textview with the correct resource id
tv.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
```